# how to draw a T network using circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

someone can help me to draw this using circuitikz package, thanks in advance.
the T-network should have generic bipoles.
[image: Circuit using cuircuitikz]

Comment: We are not specialists of electrical elements. There are a lot of examples in the manual of TikZ and `circuitikz`, pick one and we'll fix the problematic part for you. Otherwise somebody has to start from scratch and that is not fun.

Comment: And on the sketch is not pi network ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to[TL, l=TX line] (2,0)
        to[generic, l=$G1$] (4,0) -- (5,0)
        to[generic, l=$G3$] (5,-2) node [cground] {} 
        (5,0) to[generic, l=$G2$] (7,0) node [antenna] {};

        \node (bipoleslabel) [anchor= west] at (1,-2) {Generic Bipoles};
        \draw [->, smooth] (bipoleslabel.north) .. controls +(35:2) and +(215:1.5) .. (4.7, -1);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: transmitter circuit]

Comment: @PaulStivenson, package `TikZ` in not necessary to declare, it is call by `circuitikz`. And correct environment in the `\PreviewEnvironment` is `circuitikz` not `tikzpicture`.

Comment: or if you use `standalone` class you can do all those automatically. It even has a `preview` option

Comment: I use `standalone` for a number of my own projects, but I find that it behaves strangely in certain circumstances. For that reason I avoid it for quick prototypes. In fact I tend to use this preamble first when addressing questions here, at least for those questions involving TikZ. Moreover the first circuitikz example I looked at on texample.net used the preamble that I used originally for this answer.